# AttributeError in 'sapm_celltemp' function when using 15-minute weather data resolution instead of hourly values

Tags: pvlib, pv

(I'm new here so please excuse the probably not perfectly formulated question)

I've got a problem when running the run_model() method from the ModelChain class. I want to have the option to choose between hourly data resolution and 15-minute weather data resolution. Using hourly data, the calculation works fine and delivers reasonable results. When using 15-minute resolution, an AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'exp'' comes up in the 'sapm_celltemp' function. Everything else is kept unchanged tho.

I use the CEC module and inverter database

These are the PVSystem and ModelChain parameters that I chose for the calculation:

```
**PVSystem:**
surface_tilt=15
surface_azimuth=183
albedo=None
surface_type='sea'
module=''
module_parameters=
  cec_modules
  ['CSUN_Eurasia_Energy_Systems_Industry_and_Trade_CSUN325_72P']
modules_per_string=18
strings_per_inverter=4
inverter=''
inverter_parameters=
  cec_inverters['Fronius_USA__Fronius_Symo_20_0_3_480_480V__CEC_2015_']
racking_model='open_rack_cell_glassback'
losses_parameters=None

**ModelChain**
system=PVSystem
location=Location
orientation_strategy=None
clearsky_model='ineichen'
transposition_model='haydavies'
solar_position_model='nrel_numpy'
airmass_model='kastenyoung1989'
dc_model='cec'
ac_model=None
aoi_model='physical'
spectral_model='no_loss'
temp_model='sapm'
losses_model='no_loss'
```

Does anyone have a similar problem or knows what could cause the error?
Thanks in advance

Cheers, Felix

Comment: I've not seen any issue like this before so can you post a brief reproducible example?

Comment: I can not create a reproducible example. When I try to recreate the error it does not appear anymore. However, in my original program I am not able to solve the issue. I import the weather data from a csv file, but do not know how I can attach this file here for you to use. With a weather dataframe created manually without csv import, the error does not occure.

The error appears in line 1883 in sapm_celltemp: temp_module = pd.Series(poa_global*np.exp(a + b*wind_speed) + temp_air)

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'exp'

Comment: perhaps double check the dtypes of the dataframe are as you expect. or remove pvlib from the equation and manually try similar np operations on each of your columns.

Comment: probably the same as https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/issues/657